# Task.Run does not run the methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a weird bug in an ASP.NET application. I have 2 methods that calculate the interest for a loan and the principal which are inserted in a CSV file. The weird thing is that if I wrap the calculations in a Task.Run() the first time when I start the application the calculations are not done and I receive value 0 in the CSV. The second time when the calculations are run(while the application is still running), they are correctly calculated and inserted in the CSV file. I disabled the Task.Run() and I run the calculation and I did not encounter this bug anymore. Also, when the calculations run in the Task.Run(), I tried to debug the application, and If I debug and run the code, the calculations are done correctly and inserted into the CSV file(even the first time when I run the application). I believe it's a thread issue but I'm not sure what the problem is.
These are the 2 methods that are doing the calculations:

```
 public  static double CalculateInterestRate(IBankingModel bm)
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    switch (bm.IsVariable)
                    {
                        case true:
                            InterestRate = (EURIBOR + FixedRateE) * bm.LoanAmount;
                            break;
                        case false:
                            InterestRate = bm.InterestPercent * bm.LoanAmount;
                            break;
                    }
                });
                return InterestRate;
            }

public static double CalculatePrincipal(IBankingModel bm)
 {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Principal = bm.LoanAmount - InterestRate;
            });           

            return Principal;
 }
```

And this is the method that inserts the data:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Insert(BankingModel bm)
        {
            using (StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter(_path.MapPath, true))
            {

                a.WriteLine($"{bm.PIN},{bm.Name},{bm.Surname},{bm.LoanAmount}," +
                    $"{bm.InterestPercent},{bm.IsVariable},{Matrix.CalculateInterestRate(bm).ToString()},{Matrix.CalculatePrincipal(bm).ToString()}");

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* you are using Task.Run? It would work better without it

Comment: I'm thinking that Task.Run(),because the calculations are done on the processor,it would use a new thread from the thread pool and it would run the calculations faster,improving the speed of the application.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: These are very simple calculations. The switch to another core would probably take more time than you would save. And it may cause the calculation to happen *after* you return the previous value

Comment: Those are not cpu intensive calculations and will not benefit from running on a separate thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By calling `Task.Run(() =>...`  you are just assigning that function  to be executed in a new thread asynchronously. And you are not waiting for it to complete. And `return` is executed immediately without waiting for the task to be finished. That's why the result is 0. You have to use `async/await` for waiting that task to be completed:

```
public static async Task<double> CalculatePrincipal(IBankingModel bm)
 {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
           //... some time-consuming operation
           Principal = bm.LoanAmount - InterestRate;
      });       

      return Principal;    
 }
```

And in that case, you have to use `await` as well while calling `CalculatePrincipal`:

```
var result = await CalculatePrincipal(bm);
```

But, if that calculation is not a time-consuming operation, then there is no need to use `Task`. Just return the difference:

```
public static double CalculatePrincipal(IBankingModel bm)
{
    return  bm.LoanAmount - InterestRate;
}
```

Comment: Ok,I understand the explication,but it seems that return is executed immediately only the first time when I'm running the calculations in the application,after that the calculations are returned correctly.Do you have any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: @WorkoutChannel It will always be executed immediately. May be you are seeing the result, because you are setting `Principal` inside that `Task`.